# A significantly easy rebus

Tags: rebus

Really easy rebus but wanted to share nonetheless:
[image]

Comment: [The obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1015/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the answer is

> A world apart

Comment: There is only one A, not two like in your answer.

Comment: @Untitpoi Parts of hints themselves can be used as parts of other hints. One piece of information does not need to be only useful once in solving a puzzle. In this case, its made somewhat obvious, though I can think of an alternative solution that only has one A.

Comment: Rather than _30 characters needed_ you could add an explanation as how you came to this conclusion and why you think it's the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it means

> A part of the world

Comment: You beat me to it. I'd just add a "the".